# How to have different strings displaying different text each time user opens app?

Tags: android, eclipse, string, random

Basically the app opens up to a menu and at the top it says Welcome to bla bla. I want to change that every time they open the app to something different each time so next time it would say. Bla bla is awesome and so are you. Next time it may display a different text. Basically I want to be able to create a string array possibly and each time the user opens the app/activity, a random string is selected and displayed. If there is a better way of going it by a string array, I am open to suggestions. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use shared preferences and every time the user start the application show another sentence.

you should save the sentences in your shared preferences and to save a counter for 
retrieving the index your in the str array.

should be like:

```
    String Sentences = "sen one, sen two, sen three, sen four";
int counter = 0;
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("sentences", Sentences);
editor.putInt("counter", counter);
editor.commit();
```

here you save in your device the sentences and the counter.

now how you get the current sentence and display?
should be like:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor editor = prefs.edit()
String sen = prefs.getString("sentences", "");
int counter = prefs.getInt("counter", 0);
String[] fetchArray= sen.split(",");

//now you should display fetchArray[counter].
tv_1.settext(fetchArray[counter] + "");

counter = counter+1;

if (counter == fetchArray[counter].length)
    counter = 0;

editor.putInt("counter", counter);
editor.commit();
```

this should perfectly work.
good night.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try it!

Answer (score 1):

Build an array of your strings, and pick a random one each time.

For example this will generate a random number between 0 and 99:

```
Random ran = new Random();
randomNum  = ran.nextInt(100);
```

So, you can then call a string from your array: `myArray.get(randomNum)`.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try the shared preferences and I will keep that way in mind if I want to go that way. I appreciate your answer